# What is the name of this and how to code it in xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

I am sorting the restaurants by various means and I used overflow menu that seems old. I want to change it like the given picture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_coo_layout"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:background="@color/tomato_red"
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:title="All Restaurants"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_menu_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What changes to be done here to get the desired result.

Comment: they are called chips: read more about them here https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are Chips and you can use it in your app foollowing this istructions (directly from github readme)

Material Components for Android is available through Google's Maven Repository. To use it:

1. Open the build.gradle file for your application.

2.Make sure that the repositories section includes Google's Maven Repository google(). For example:

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
  }
```

Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
  dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
  }
```

A Chip can be added in a layout like so (.XML):

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"/>
```

Changes to a chip can be observed like so:

```
chip.setOnClickListener {
   // Responds to chip click
}

chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener {
    // Responds to chip's close icon click if one is present
}

chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chip, isChecked ->
    // Responds to chip checked/unchecked
}
```